# Typing `set -e` kills bash

Tags: bash

In `bash` version `4.4.12`, when I type:

```
set -e
```

at the command prompt, the shell exits, returning `128`.

Why does this happen when `set -u` is fine?

Comment: Do you have anything fancy in your prompt, or in a debug command?

Comment: Do you have something set up to run code in between commands? What does `echo $PROMPT_COMMAND` give? `echo $PS1`? `trap`?

Comment: My fix was to add `local -; set +e` inside the function which `$PROMPT_COMMAND` called. This restores the original `$-` when the function returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If, for example, you have a command that is returning a non-zero exit status as part of the expansion of `PROMPT_COMMAND` (which is executed before printing the prompt in `bash`), then this will trigger the shell to exit immediately when you set the `errexit` option with `set -e`.

Another possibility is that there is a `DEBUG` trap set that returns a non-zero exit status. A `DEBUG` trap is however executed *before* a command is invoked, so it would not cause the shell to exit immediately as you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after `set -e`, but instead before launching the next command.

With `set -u` you set the `nounset` shell option.  This option will issue cause the shell to issue an error if you try to expand any unset variable apart form `$@` and `$*`.  It will not cause the shell to exit, unless `set -e` is also in effect.

With `set -u` in effect *and* an unset variable in `PS1`, the shell *will* exit as soon as you set the `errexit` option with `set -e`.

Comment: [`$PS1` doesn't support running commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Controlling-the-Prompt). Also, the command could be running via a DEBUG trap.

Comment: @TomHale Thanks for the `DEBUG` trap reminder.  If `PS1` contains a command substitution that returns a non-zero exit status, the shell will exit if `set -e` is set. Try it with `PS1=$(false)`.

Comment: You're right on the `DEBUG` trap, however: `PS1=$(false); set -e; echo OK` is just fine. (The expansion of $() occurs only once, and would occurred while `set +e` was in effect.)

Comment: @TomHale Ah, you are correct. I meant `PS1='$(false)'`, but that will not make a difference. I will update. Thanks!